# Tom travels extensively all over. He was trying to figure out

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

The missing members in the following sequence.

$A$, $A$, $A$, $A$, $?$, $?$, $?$

Please help him out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it:

> E, NA, SA

because:

> these are the initial letters of the [continents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continent) in alphabetical order (Africa, Antartica, Asia, Australia, Europe, North America, South America).

Comment: Yes....got it!!